# Calcular a média de uma variável para cada tipo de flor de uma coluna

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Na coluna species do dataset, tenho essas especies de flor:

```
df['species'].unique()
output: array(['Iris-setosa', 'Iris-versicolor', 'Iris-virginica']
```

Preciso fazer a média para cada especie de flor utilizando a variável `sepal_width` do dataset:

```
df.sepal_width.head()
0    3.5
1    3.0
2    3.2
3    3.1
4    3.6
```

Eu só sei fazer uma por uma utilizando este código, por exemplo:

```
   especie_iris_setosa = df[df['species'] == 'Iris-setosa'] #traz todas as linhas que contenham a especie Iris-setosa
   especie_iris_setosa['sepal_length'].mean()
   output: 5.005999999999999
```

Como posso fazer um loop que faça a média do `sepal_width` para cada espécie de flor da coluna `species`?

Acho que seria algo tipo assim: `for i in df.species:` mas nāo sei como fazer.

Answer (score 0):

Agrupe o dataset pela espécie de flor, selecione a coluna de largura das sépalas e aplique a função de média em cada grupo.

```py
df_medias = df.groupby(['species'], as_index=False)['sepal_width'].mean()
```

O `df_medias` é um novo dataframe com 2 colunas:

- `species`, contém o nome de cada espécie; e
- `sepal_width`, contém a média de largura das sépalas daquela espécie.

Referências:

- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html#pandas.DataFrame.groupby
- https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.mean.html